# Seamless audio file concatenator for a js project?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api, howler.js

I am trying to join/concatenate multiple audio files in a JavaScript project, and have tried using libraries like Crunker & Howler, but when I join concatenate my audio files, there is a small blank of silence between my joined audio files.  Does anyone know of a library or Service that can seamlessly join audio files, with no blank space in between them?

Comment: Can you verify that the audio files being concatenated do not have silence encoded? This could be done by loading and inspecting them in Audacity. IDK how these utilities (crunker, howler) work but concatenating audio can be problematic. Discontinuities between two audio files will generally cause a click, so some sort of cross-fading should happen if the files don't fade in from and out to silence.

Answer (score 0):

If they are any type of compressed files (ie mp3) you won't get a clean concatenation.  I've used FFmpeg with great success but only on uncompressed audio (ie .wav) and then encode the output to a compressed format.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).